# How to extract output of retire.js into a file from maven execution

Tags: java, maven, retire

I am using retire.js plugin in maven pom file. The vulnerability details are listed along with the build output.

I would like to extract the retire.js output into a separate file.

Can you please suggest some ways to extract only retire.js data into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the [source code of retire.js Maven plugin](https://github.com/h3xstream/burp-retire-js/blob/master/retirejs-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/h3xstream/retirejs/RetireJsScan.java) we can notice that the log output from retirejs is redirected into Maven's stream (in `initMiniLog()`). And there seem to be no specific configuration for it.

However, with a bit of tweaking we can set up Maven to gather these logs. So I can suggest the following:

1) By default Maven uses slf4j-simple logger, remove its jar from `{M2_HOME}/lib`.

2) Place in the same folder a logging library that supports output into files, for example Logback: `logback-classic-*.jar` and `logback-core-*.jar`.

3) Define a configuration that will output everything into stdout and only the things that you are looking for into the file. `logback.xml` should be placed into `{M2_HOME}/conf/logging`. For example, I used the following draft configuration to extract the output of maven-compiler-plugin into maven.log in the current folder:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>./maven.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%level - %message%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!-- 
     specify the package of retirejs: com.h3xstream.retirejs
  -->
  <logger name="org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

4) Execute your build command...